Is it possible to replicate across projects when doing "Cross-region dataset replication" in BigQuery?
I would like to replicate datasets across projects and regions.
I think "cross-region dataset replication" is an option, but I couldn't find a sample query that could cross projects, and I didn't see any restrictions that say replication between projects is not possible, so I'm not sure if it's possible to use the "cross-region dataset replication" option. I could not figure out if it is possible or not.
I think the reason there was no mention of the impossibility of replication between projects as a limitation is because it is not possible as a basic premise, but I would like to know if it is possible or not.
If it is possible, I would like to know what kind of query should be executed to make it possible.

Hi @Lana2548, Currently this is not supported and seems like a feature request. If you want this feature in google cloud BigQuery you can raise a feature request in Issue Tracker  or raise an issue with the support team.

Cross region dataset replication between projects is not supported at this time (2024-06).  I have raised a documentation issue against this article to have the restriction explicitly called out.
